# Quando é necessário utilizar o isset?

Tags: php, formulário, variáveis

Gostaria de saber quando é realmente imprescindível utilizar o `isset` nas variáveis em PHP, principalmente no caso de formulários.

O que acontece é que estou criando um grande formulário, com uns 200+ campos, que irá realizar cálculos e outras funções em PHP de acordo com o preenchimento.

Nenhum campo será de preenchimento obrigatório, e o sistema fará o "cálculo possível", com as informações fornecidas. Por enquanto, como estou testando apenas em *localhost*, não está dando problema nenhum utilizar as variáveis apenas assim por exemplo:

```
$difsal = $_POST ["Tdifsalim"];  
$saldev = $_POST ["Tdate5"];
```

Então mesmo que o campo respectivo (`Tdifsalim` p.ex.) não seja preenchido no formulário, o *script* roda normal, e dá o resultado esperado (de acordo com os campos que foram preenchidos). Mas daí fiquei em dúvida se depois, quando for colocar no servidor, terei ainda que incluir todos esses `issets` para evitar erros de requisição.

Então a pergunta é: colocar `isset` em todas as variáveis de formulário é mesmo necessário? Se for, no exemplo acima qual a forma mais simples de incluir o `isset` para que quando o campo não for preenchido, o valor da variável seja igual a **nulo** (não 0, porque pode afetar os cálculos).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não é para um código funcionar diferente em locais diferentes. Claro que pode haver problemas de permissões ou configurações específicas que pode afetar, mas em geral o que envolve apenas a lógica do código e não de bibliotecas, não é para fazer diferença.

O `isset` é necessário se você precisa saber se a variável foi previamente definida. Se isto não importar, se um valor implícito for pego der uma resultado adequado, você não precisa usar. As tais "boas práticas" indicam para sempre que possível usar a verificação e só deixar de usar quando houver um motivo para isto. Talvez você já tenha ouvido falar que uma das maiores preocupações do desenvolvimento de software, principalmente para web, é que todos os dados que entrarão na aplicação devem ser validados. Deve-se fazer todas as validações possíveis que sejam relevantes. A primeira validação deveria ser se o dado efetivamente existe.

Você deve fazer isto item por item, deve testar cada índice que pretende usar no `$_POST` ou outra informação que venha externamente.

A única coisa que pode ser feita para facilitar é criar uma função que ajude fazer a validação, assim você passaria uma lista de índices esperados e se qualquer um não estiver presente, a função acusaria um erro. O ganho não é enorme mas simplifica um pouco a lógica. O quanto isto é vantajoso depende do caso. Pode fazer assim:

```
function post_isset($indexes) {
    foreach($indexes as $index) if (!isset($_POST[$index])) return false;
    return true;
}
if (!post_isset(['nome', 'email'])) echo "deu erro";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/RsvSkZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/drwgydmv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/MultipleIsset.php).

Claro que esta versão é bem simplificado, isto pode ser melhorado para indicar onde ocorreu o erro, pode fazer funcionar com algo além do `$_POST`, enfim, tem várias sofisticações que podem ser desenvolvidas.

No seu exemplo você quer pegar um valor nulo e não um zero, pois bem, é isto que você pega quando a variável não existe, ele não pega um valor *default*, ou pelo menos o *deafult* é `null`. Mas se decidir pegar a variável direto, se o nulo te atende, ainda vai gerar pelo menos um *notice*, que não é ideal.

Tem outras formas como a da resposta do Wallace Maxters que pode obter um resultado semelhante mas o teste precisa ser feito.

Comment: Valeu, era exatamente o que eu queria saber!

Answer (score 7):

## função `isset`

De acordo com o manual do PHP, a função `isset` serve para verificar se uma variável é existente ou se ela não possui o valor igual a `NULL`. Se ela for `NULL` ou não existir, o resultado dessa função retornará `FALSE`.

## Filtragem de Dados

Como o PHP 5.2 implementou os `filters`, eu não utilizaria o `isset`, mas utilizaria as funções dessa biblioteca para filtrar melhor os dados.

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha');

if ($email && $senha) {
   // faça alguma coisa
}
```

Dê uma olhada no [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.filter.php)

## função `filter_has_var`

No caso da verificação da existência, bom seria a utilização da função `filter_has_var`. Essa função verifica a existência de variáveis externas de acordo com seu tipo (POST, GET, COOKIE).

Uma diferença interessante entre `isset` e `filter_has_var` foi relatada por um usuário na página do manual do PHP (eu testei e comprovei os resultados).

Para os exemplos abaixos os resultados são diferentes:

```
$_GET['test'] = 1;

echo filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'test') ? 'Existe' : 'Não Existe'; // Não existe

echo isset($_GET['test']) ? 'Existe' : 'Não Existe'; // Existe
```

No caso acima, o `filter_has_var` vai verificar a existência "real" da variável passado por parâmetro na url. Já o `isset` apenas verifica se existe o valor dentro da variável global `$_GET`.

Comment: Valeu Wallace, foi muito útil, vou estudar melhor estas funções.

Answer (score 5):

A função `isset` — Informa se a variável foi iniciada. Apenas isso.

A variavel `$_POST` é uma superglobal<sup>1</sup> sempre logo ela sempre existe (Set), mas o seu conteúdo pode ser vazio.

O que você pode usar é a função [empty](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) para verificar se sua variável possui valor.

```
if (!empty($_POST["email"])) {
 echo "E-mail possui valor.";
}
```

<sup>1</sup> **Superglobais** são variáveis nativas que estão sempre disponíveis em todos escopos

Fontes: [PHP: isset](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php), [PHP: empty](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php), [PHP: $_POST](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php), [PHP: Superglobais](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php), [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13045314).

Comment: `isset` também verifica se o valor é `NULL`. Ela pode existir, porém ser nula.

Comment: Valeu Laerte, vou estudar melhor o empty e as funções que o Wallace indicou. O pessoal aqui tem me ajudado muito, sou muito grato à todos.

Comment: Disponha! Aprendo muito aqui também. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sempre utilize quando uma variável provem do usuário, mas também é bom sempre verificar mesmo que os dados provenham do próprio aplicativo.

Quando você faz

```
$saldev = $_POST ["Tdate5"];
```

Está causando um erro quando o índice não existe, porém, quando a mensagem de erro não aparece na tela é devido a configuração ocultando-o e isso é uma prática ruim. 
Configure o ambiente para mostrar erros quando estiver em ambiente de desenvolvimento (localhost)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

Sempre verifique as entradas:

```
$saldev = isset( $_POST["Tdate5"] ) ? $_POST["Tdate5"] : false;
```

Comment: Ah, mas isso vai dar uma trabalheira! :) haha Então, pelo que entendi o certo é validar mesmo de alguma forma, porque embora esteja funcionando, não é uma boa prática. Estou vendo aqui entre as opções que foram colocadas, e acho que a do bigow parece mais simples (a sua forma é a que eu já ia fazer), mas valeu pela resposta. +10 Edit: pra configurar o localhost é só incluir esta linha no apache2.conf? Valeu por isso tmb!

Comment: Essa "trabalheira" pode ser reduzida com uso de bibliotecas ou frameworks. Mas se quiser criar o seu próprio método, basta criar uma classe ou uma simples função que abstraia e verifique os dados do $_REQUEST. Então vc define as regras de validação essenciais com opção para customizar.

Comment: "o certo é validar mesmo de alguma forma, porque embora esteja funcionando" Na verdade não está "funcionando" de forma segura. Um erro está sendo gerado porém está sendo ignorado. O modo como está fazendo, quando for rodar num ambiente de configurações restritas, com certeza dará problemas. Aí vem aquelas famosas perguntas "funciona localhost e não funciona no server" rsrsr..

Comment: @gustavox Entenda que você está generalizando dois conceitos diferentes: A entrada de dados e validação de dados. A entrada de dados sempre deve ser verificada. O php não aceita dados indeterminados. Mesmo que o seu campo não tenha nada preenchido é obrigatório que haja pelo menos um valor `false` ou `null` setado na variável. Garantir que os dados foram recebidos não garante que são válidos, ainda que válidos não garante se foram recebidos. Por fim, particularmente eu gosto dessa maneira de receber os dados, se você tiver um netbeans em mãos, fica ágil ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Ah algum tempo implemente esta funcao :

```
        /**
         * campoNecessario
         *
         * Realiza uma verificacao no(s) campo(s) passado(s), que retorna "true",
         * caso esteja "empty", o "empty" tambem considera valor "0" como "empty",
         * por isto se quiser permitir valores zerados defina o segundo parâmetro
         * como "true".
         * Realiza um verificacao caso o campo nao esteja exatamente igual a ER,
         * lembrando que "preg_match" retorna 1 caso ER = //
         *
         * @name        campoNecessario
         * @param       $campos
         * @param       $campoZerado
         * @param       $expressaoRegular
         * @return      boolean
         * @author      Guilherme Lautert
         * @since       00/00/0000 00:00:00
         * @modified    26/02/2015 13:35:10
         */
        public function campoNecessario($campos, $campoZerado = FALSE, $expressaoRegular = 'A'){
            switch ($expressaoRegular){
                case 'A':  // all
                    $expressaoRegular = '//';
                break;
                case 'N': // numeros
                    $expressaoRegular = '/^[0-9]+$/i';
                break;
                case 'L': // letras
                    $expressaoRegular = '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/i';
                break;
                case 'NL': // letras e numeros
                    $expressaoRegular = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i';
                break;
                default:
                    $expressaoRegular;
                break;
            }

            if(is_array($campos)){
                foreach ($campos as $key => $campo){
                    if(is_array($campo)){
                        return $this->campoNecessario($campo, $campoZerado, $expressaoRegular);
                    }else{
                        if($campoZerado){
                            if(empty($campo) && ($campo !== "0")){
                                return TRUE;
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(empty($campo) || $campo == "0,00" || $campo == "0.00"){
                                return TRUE;
                            }
                        }
                        if(!preg_match($expressaoRegular, $campo)){
                            return TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if($campoZerado){
                    if(empty($campos) && ($campos !== "0")){
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(empty($campos) || $campos == "0,00" || $campos == "0.00"){
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                }
                if(!preg_match($expressaoRegular, $campos)){
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
```

Espero que ajude.