# Como saber se o form é enviado

Tags: php

Como saber quando o form for enviado e sem os campos em input estarem em branco?

Me indicaram o `isset` para realizar esta ação mas eu não entendi direito o uso do `isset`

Comment: Relacionado: [Quando é necessário utilizar o isset?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58355/91)

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4388/ap-que-d%C3%A1-positivo-em-tudo-menos-no-correto-e-aceita-o-mais-errado-kkk

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Suponha um formulário com campo de entrada chamado "foo":

```
<form method="get" action="script.php">
<input type="text" name="foo" size="10" />
</form>
```

O formulário enviará os dados para o arquivo "script.php".

Suponha que esse seja o código de "script.php":

```
$campo = 'foo'; //nome do campo no formulario.

/**
Obtém o array de dados da variável global.
Note que aqui receberá tanto como GET quanto como POST ou outros métodos como PUT, DELETE, etc.
Nesse caso, o recomendado é validar o método recebido. 
Como esse não é o foco da pergunta e também para evitar escrever algo muito complexo, considerando que o AP não sabe nem o que é um isset(), vamos manter a coisa simplificada.
*/
$p = $GLOBALS['_'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']];

/**
Verifica se o índice (o campo do fomrulário ou parâmetro de url) existe dentro da global.
*/
if (!isset($p[$campo])) {
   echo 'índice inexistente'; exit;
}

/**
Remove espaços vazios do início e do fim da string, caso existam.
Isso ajuda a definir se o valor está realmente vazio. Todavia, caso a regra de negócio permita caracteres de espaço livremente, essa verificação deve ser evitada, obviamente. 
*/
$val = trim($p[$campo]);

/**
Verifica se o valor é vazio.
*/
if(empty($val)) {
   echo 'O campo '.$campo.' está vazio'; exit;
}

/**
Por fim, o resultado final.
*/
echo 'O valor de '.$campo.' é: '.$val;
```

**Erros comuns que comumente vemos em respostas para esse tipo de pergunta**

```
$valor = $_POST['valor'];

  if(empty($valor){
    echo 'vazio';
  }
```

Por quê isso é errado?

Por que quando o índice do array global $_POST for inexistente, será disparado um erro de `undefined index`. Quando não dispara erro é porque o ambiente está mal configurado. Como a maioria dos ambientes é mal configurado, muitos acabam acreditando que o uso da função `empty()`, para esse caso, seja adequado.

Em muitos foruns e blogs é comum encontrarmos isso como solução, infelizmente e como resultado temos essa grande disseminação de informação errônea.

Resumindo, a função `empty()` como o próprio nome sugere, verifica se uma *string* ou *array* é vazio. Não verifica se existe.

A função `isset()` significa, a grosso modo "está setado?".

Tal como a função `empty()`, o nome é sugestivo e intuitivo tal como a documentação é bem clara  sobre as suas funcionalidades. (http://php.net/empty e http://php.net/isset)

Outro erro encontrado também nas respostas aqui dadas:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
if (!isset($nome)) {
   echo 'variável vazia';
}
```

Isso também emitirá erro caso o índice seja inexistente.

O correto seria

```
if (!isset($_POST['nome'])) {
   echo 'variável é inexistente';
}
```

Note que a frase também estava incorreta. Pois variável vazia é diferente de variável inexistente.

**Observações finais**

Como pudemos ver, um simples $_GET e $_POST é muito mais complexo do que vemos na maioria das respostas e dicas em blogs e fórums diversos.

São detalhes essenciais para construção de um sistema sólido.

Comment: Cara, só pra eu entender, lembre-se que ainda to aprendendo, e certas coisas ainda precisam desenhadas pra mim rsrs, mas olha só, se eu não usar apenas uma variável global (que pelo que entendi da resposta pega todos os campos do formulário e cria a variável com o mesmo name... é isso?), mas digamos que cada campo de formulário tenha uma variável diferente, vale a mesma regra? Tipo, pra fazer o certo eu tenho que usar `isset`, `trim`e `empty` em todas as variáveis? +11

Comment: E se for um número seria legal ainda acrescentar `is_numeric` por exemplo?  Ou daí já é exagero?

Comment: Acho que não expliquei direito, digamos que cada variável seja declarada isoladamente... eu tenho declarado ou apenas com `isset` ou com `empty` num operador ternário (e vc sempre usou com `if`e tal), quer dizer, meu código está uma m@$%$ né... Se quiser só explicar alguma coisa aqui nos coments depois eu crio uma outra pergunta se achar melhor.... valeu...

Comment: O tratamento dos parâmetros depende do modelo de negócios. Nem tudo que receber deve ser necessariamente filtrado, sanitizado, etc.. é complicado tentar te explicar nesse espaço pequeno de comentário. Acho que te deixará com mais dúvidas.. principalmente sobre o tal uso do $GLOBALS.   rsrs.. Mas falando rapidamente, o $GLOBALS é meramente uma técnica para abstrair os dados de forma mais dinâmica. Note que não há chamadas específicas para $_GET ou $_POST. Escrevi de um forma generérica que permite flexibilidade. Mas isso é assunto para outra conversa. Inviável postar aqui.

Comment: Daniel, criei uma [pequena pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89960/como-validar-cada-tipo-de-dado-recebido-de-um-formul%c3%a1rio) (rsrs) sobre minha dúvidas. valeu por enquanto! abs

Answer (score 9):

`$_POST` é um *array* e você pode utilizar `count( $_POST )` para verificar se algo foi enviado; senão, retornará 0.

Mas `empty( $_POST )` também fará a verificação, com a diferença que retornará `true`ou `false` e é uma função mais genérica (você pode utilizar com outros tipos de variáveis).

Para saber se existe uma chave no array, você pode utilizar array_key_exists( 'chave', $_POST  ), mas você pode utilizar também `isset( $_POST[ 'chave' ] )` que é mais genérica.

`isset` retorna TRUE se a variável (e chave / propriedade informada) foi definida. `empty` retorna TRUE se NÃO foi definida ou seu valor for falso: `false, 0, '0', '', null` ou array vazio - `[] / array()`.

`isset` ou `empty`, além de mais genéricos, são mais rápidos que `array_key_exists()` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884609/array-key-existskey-array-vs-emptyarraykey) e sutilmente mais rápidos que `count()` 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216110/checking-for-empty-arrays-count-vs-empty).

Portanto, **recomendo** `isset`ou `empty` em vez de `array_key_exists` ou `count`.

***OBS***: Agradeço ao *Daniel Omine* pelo seu questionamento, que me levou à correção e aperfeiçoamento da minha resposta.

Answer (score 4):

No arquivo que você recebe os dados via POST, você pode usar:

```
if (getenv('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') { /* faz alguma coisa */ }
```

**OBS: getenv() não funciona com ISAPI**

E mais uma opção, que é a mais usada, é usar isset. O isset() retorna true se a variável foi definida e false se caso ela não foi definida.

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) { /* faz alguma coisa */ }
```

[Documentação isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais simples de saber se um post foi enviado é através do `REQUEST_METHOD`.

Tente fazer algo como:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

}
```

`REQUEST_METHOD` indica qual é o método utilizado na requisição. Não há restrições para seu uso.

Answer (score -2):

Só uma dica:

Em vez de verificar se os campos foram enviados em branco, não seria melhor impedir que isso ocorra?

```js
function valida() {

  var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value,
      sobrenome = document.getElementById('sobrenome').value;
 
  if( ! nome ) {
    alert('Nome não foi preenchido');
    return false;
  } else if( ! sobrenome ) {
      alert('Sobrenome não foi preenchido');
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('Seu formulário foi enviado!');
    return true;
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return valida();">
  Nome:
  <br>
  <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" />
  <br><br>
  Sobrenome:
  <br>
  <input id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" type="text" />
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Faça uma validação de formulário em javascript antes de enviar como no exemplo acima. No Google você acha muitos exemplos.

Comment: Que tal você trazer um exemplo e [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/90227/edit) sua resposta? Assim ela fica mais completa, você contribui com o site e, principalmente, com várias outras pessoas que tem/terão essa mesma dúvida.

Comment: Editei o post e inseri um exemplo como foi pedido!

Answer (score -4):

Você pode usar `isset` para verificar se um campo foi "enviado" ou pode também usar `empty`.

Usando `isset`:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
if (!isset($nome)) {
   echo 'variável vazia';
}
```

Note que antes da função `isset` coloquei um ponto de exclamação, isso faz com que o atributo a seguir retorne o contrario, ou seja, `false`.
exemplo:

```
if (isset($nome))...// Se a variável nome conter algum valor...
if (!isset($nome))...// Se a variável nome não conter alguma valor...
```

usando `empty`:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
if (empty($nome)) {
    echo 'variavel vazia';
```

Você pode usar também a mesma logica para o `empty`, por exemplo:

```
if (empty($nome))...// Se a variável nome estiver vazia...
if (!empty($nome))...// Se a variável NÃO estiver vazia...
```

Comment: O uso do `empty()` para esse caso é desaconselhável.

Comment: E outro ponto é, está usando isset no lugar errado.. srrs seria ser isset($_POST...)