# index indefinida

Tags: php

Boa noite, Tenho um código onde faço um insert into,mas esta me retornando erro, e não estou conseguindo resolver, no mesmo campo é printado no banco de dados, pagina e content. A pagina é cadastrada porem a content causa erro; e o erro
 é: Notice: Undefined index: content 
meu código:

```
       $pagina_editar = $_POST['pagina'];
       $content_editar = $_POST['content'];
       if(isset($_POST['cadastrar']) && $_POST['cadastrar'] == 'envia_form'){
$cadatrar_pagina = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO lp_page (pagina, content) VALUES ('$pagina_editar', '$content_editar')")or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
       }

       if(isset($_POST['editar_post']) && $_POST['editar_post'] == 'envia_form'){
$atualiza_pagina = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE lp_page SET content='$content_editar' WHERE pagina = '$pagina_editar'") or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
       }

      $pagina_de_edicao = $_POST['pagina'];

        $pega_pagina = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT id, pagina, content FROM lp_page WHERE pagina = '$pagina_de_edicao'")or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
           if(@mysqli_num_rows($pega_pagina) <= '0'){
     ?>

     <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cadastrar_pagina">
     <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="<?php echo $pagina_de_edicao;?>" />
     <textarea name="content" rows="30" cols=""></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="cadastrar" value="envia_form" />
     <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="Cadastrar" class="cadastro_btn" />
     </form>    

     <?php

      }else{
        while($res_pagina = mysqli_fetch_array($pega_pagina)){
            $id = $res_pagina[0];
              $pagina = $res_pagina[1];
                $content = $res_pagina[2];  
   ?>
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="edita_pagina">
       <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="<?php echo $pagina_de_edicao;?>"/>
      <textarea name="content" cols="" rows="30"> <?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="editar_post" value="envia_form" />
      <input name="Editar" type="submit" value="Editar" class="cadastro_btn" />
      </form>
<?php
}
 }
 ?>
```

o erro esta acontecendo na linha: $content_editar = $_POST['content'];
 alguém pode  ajudar-me? obrigado

Comment: Porquê o formulário tem `multiplart/form-data` ? O `<form ...>` e `</form>` devem estar fora do _looping_. Experimenta essas alterações, e se possível adiciona também o código `PHP`.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89105/como-saber-se-o-form-%C3%A9-enviado/89142#89142

Comment: esse outro também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89960/como-validar-cada-tipo-de-dado-recebido-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio/90026#90026

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, "Notice" não é erro.

O php está só te notificando que o elemento do array $_POST, cuja index é 'content', não foi definido.

Está facil de saber o porque disso: 
Veja que vc define a variável '$content_editar' **antes** de verificar se existe uma requisição do tipo POST, ou seja, se existe o array $_POST.

Solução: Defina as variaveis depois de verificar se existe a requisição do tipo POST.

```
if(
 isset($_POST['cadastrar']) && 
 $_POST['cadastrar'] == 'envia_form')
{
  $pagina_editar = $_POST['pagina'];
  $content_editar = $_POST['content'];
  $cadatrar_pagina = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO lp_page (pagina, content) VALUES ('$pagina_editar', '$content_editar')")or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
}
```

Comment: acho que vc esqueceu de tratar as outras duas variáveis  `$_POST['pagina']` e  `$_POST['content']`. Mas isso é de menos.. o que vale é corrigir o erro de lógica do AP.

Comment: Muito obrigado querido Marcos Kubis, valeu.Tenho tido muitas dificuldades em php, pois sou iniciante. o bom é que encontramos pessoas que dedicadas em ajudar. Que Cristo continue te abençoando.Obrigado.