# Saber se existem espaços em branco

Tags: php

Boa comunidade! 
Tenho a seguinte duvida. Como poderei alertar o utilizador de que existem espaços em branco no campo `username`?

Assim é como estou a validar o `username` agora:

```
if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
 $nameErr = "Escolha um username.";
   } else {
 $uname = test_input($_POST["username"]);
 $v1='ok';

 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-0-9-_]*$/",$uname)) {
   $nameErr = "Somente letras e números."; 
 }
}
```

A solução foi esta:

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
  $nameErr = "Escolha um username.";
   } else {
 $uname = test_input($_POST["username"]);

 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace

 // aqui
 if (!ereg("(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z\_0-9\.-]*))$", $_POST["username"]) ) {

   $nameErr = "Somente letras e números."; 
 }
```

}

Comment: Validação de form? Já cogitou usar javascript? Esse tipo de validação do lado do servidor só desperdiça requisição e processamento.

Comment: Obrigado por responder @DiegoFelipe. Sim é validação de formulário de registo. Neste caso, o campo "username". eu não quero espaços no username... Estou pelo php mesmo

Comment: @Diego Felipe, A validação server-side sempre deve ser executada independente de existir validação client-side.

Comment: Modifique a sua pergunta, @David Concha, pois da forma como está diferente do que comentou. Um campo em branco é muito diferente de remover espaços num campo específico.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe validação só é do lado do servidor. Do lado do cliente você só consegue fazer uma mera checagem preliminar, mas não tem como evitar o envio de dados inadequados.

Comment: @DanielOmine sim, mas tendo a validação do lado do cliente, já evita muitas requisições simplesmente porque um campo ou outro não foi preenchido. Vejo o php mais para confirmar a validação(o usuario pode desativar o javascript) ou como segurança de que os dados estão realmente sendo passados corretamente.

Comment: @Bacco mas você não concorda que reduz bastante o número de requisições desperdiçadas por causa de validação que poderiam ser alertas ao user antes de se submeter?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Eu nao concordo com a parte que você disse que "essa validação só desperdiça requisição e processamento", pois ela fundamental para integridade de dados é sempre a do servidor. Como economia de banda e requisição, eu concordo que pré-validação é bom (essa parte eu nem questionei, aliás).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tente**

```
<?php
$username = trim($_POST["username"]);

if(empty($username) || is_null($username)){
echo 'Preencha o seu username!';
}else{
echo 'Tudo OK';
}
?>
```

A função `trim` limpa os espaços da esquerda e direita.
A função `empty` verifica se o campo é vazio.
A função `is_null` verifica se o campo é do tipo `NULL`

Caso queira remover espaços de um campo você pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
$username = str_replace(" ", "", trim($_POST["username"]));
//Removerá todos os espaços do username
?>
```

Para ficar melhor, use sempre `required` nas tags `HTML` (dos inputs) que você quer que seja obrigatórios, exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```

Assim quando o usuário submeter o formulário e o campo estiver vazio ele automaticamente exibe uma mensagem para o usuário preencher o campo, sendo assim, não deixa submeter o form antes de preencher aquele campo.

Para aceitar somente caracteres "normais":

```
<?php
if (!ereg("^([A-Za-z0-9_-])", $_POST["username"]) ) {
    echo "Não use caracteres especiais nem espaços!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Se o indice do post não existir, isso vai disparar um erro.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe vai disparar um _warning_ na verdade.

Comment: Eu não queria remover os espaços, e sim alertar o utilizador q existem espaços em branco no campo `username`

Comment: Verifique o último exemplo que dei com `ereg`

Comment: usei o seu `ereg` e continua não mostrando o erro de que existem espaços. vou analisar melhor o meu código.

Comment: ereg_ foi depreciada no php5.3 e removida no 7.

Answer (score 4):

Numa expressão regular o `\s` significa espaço em branco. Pode trocar o `[a-zA-Z-0-9-_]` por `\s`, isso capturará.

```
if(preg_match("/\s*/",$uname)){
   echo 'espaço em branco';
}else{
    echo 'nome válido.';
}
```

Conforme o comentário Guilherme Lautert, o `\s` além do espaço em branco significa outros caracteres como  `\t\r\n\f\v`

Comment: `\s = [ \t\r\n\f\v]`, acho que dever ser só `' '` mesmo :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, haha depende do caso, tem gente que não gosta de espaços entre linhas ou remove eles dos parenteses `funcao ( $param );` aí o cara ve um espaço na regex e acha que está atoa e remove ele :P.

Comment: Compreendo, mas sempre saliento isso, pois o pessoal sempre divulga `\s` como sendo `' '`, mas na verdade é muito mais, ate "tab vertical" (`\v`), que nem sei o que é isso :P

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert [What is a vertical tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3380538/1342547) a dois minutos atrás eu também não sabia haha xD

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    /**
    Aqui remove não somente o caracter de espaço ansi, como também o caracter de espaço multibyte, do idioma japonês.
    */
    $str = mbstr_replace(array('　', ' '), '', $_POST['username']);

    /**
    Aqui comparamos a string original com a string sanitizada. Se forem diferentes, quer dizer que existia espaços.
    */
    if ($_POST['username'] != $str) {
        echo 'digitou o nome com espaços';
    }
}
```

O exemplo é meramente didático. Esteja ciente, por favor. 
Adapte o exemplo conforme a sua necessidade.

Para entender melhor veja esse tópico que fala sobre sanitização, filtragem e validação: [Como saber se o form é enviado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89105/como-saber-se-o-form-%c3%a9-enviado)

Answer (score 1):

**Tente isso:**

```
<?php
    //Tira os espaços em branco do começo e do fim
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);

    if(empty($username) || is_null($username)) {
        echo 'O username não pode ser vazio';
    } else if (strrpos($username, " ") !== false) { //Procura a última ocorrência de espaço
        echo 'Não pode haver espaços no meio do username';
    } else {
        echo 'Username válido';
    }
?>
```