# Undefined index: txtnum in C:\xampp\htdocs\fator.php on line 2, alguém pode ajudar com esse erro?

Tags: php, xampp

segue os códigos:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fatoração</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="fator.php">
        Numero: <input type="text" name="txtnum"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Calcular">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $num = $_POST["txtnum"];
    $variavel = $num;
    $fatorial = $variavel;

    while ($variavel > 1) {
        $fatorial = $fatorial*($variavel-1);
        $variavel--;
    }
    echo "Número fatorado: $fatorial";
?>
```

Comment: retirei, continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: [Como saber se o form é enviado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89105/91)

Comment: Na primeira execução `$_POST["txtnum"]` não existe, um `isset()` nele já resolve.

Comment: tenta usar `isset()` no botão `Calcular`

Comment: Quando eu dou o isset ele não retorna nada, e testando com o empty da verdadeiro(variável vazia).