# Aplicação prática do isset() e unset() no PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de uma aplicação prática das funções `isset()` e `unset()`.
Estou estudando PHP mas não entendi muito bem como isso pode ser aplicado no desenvolvimento de alguma aplicação.

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `isset`

`isset` tem como finalidade verificar se uma variável existe ou se ela não é null. Sendo asim, `isset` faz todo sentido no desenvolvimento de uma aplicação em PHP.

Imagine o seguinte cenário: Você precisa saber se um determinado valor foi passado na url, via parâmetro `GET`. Para saber se esse valor existe, você precisa utilizar a função `isset`.

Veja:

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $page = $_GET['page'];
   require __DIR__ . '/pages/' . $page . '.php';
}
```

No exemplo acima, se você tentasse capturar a variável `$_GET['page']` diretamente, sem verificar antes a existência daquele índice, você faria com que, caso fosse omitido na url o valor `page`, fosse emitido um erro semelhante a esse:

> Notice: undefined index "page"

Leia mais em:

[Quando é necessário utilizar o isset?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58355/quando-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio-utilizar-o-isset)

## `unset`

A função `unset`  por sua vez tem como finalidade remover uma variável. O seu uso é menos comum do que o `isset`.

Ela tem como finalidade apenas remover uma variável, fazendo com que a mesma deixe de existir.

Não tenho um exemplo prático, mas você poderia utilizar por exemplo em uma variável que guarda um nome de um arquivo que acaba de ser deletado. Se ele acaba de ser deletado, você não precisa mais do nome dele.

Então

```
 $arquivo = 'dir/nome_do_arquivo.txt';

 unlink($arquivo);

 unset($arquivo);
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigada, Wallace. Ajudou muito!!! :)

Comment: Conte conosco para o que vocês precisar