# Enviar mensagem após o click do botão submit

Tags: php, html

Como faço para identificar com PHP se um botão submit foi clicado? e após o click quero enviar uma mensagem de confirmação de click!.
Detalhe tudo em PHP.!!!

Assim não está funcionando não

```
<form  method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="salario"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="bonificacao"><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="btn">
</form>

<?php

$btn = $_POST['btn'];

if(!$btn){

   echo " O botão foi clicado ";

}else{

}
```

Comment: Não funciona nem quando você pressiona o botão? Logo que carrega a página a primeira vez é esperado dar errado, já que você estará fazendo uma requisição GET e recuperando valores POST que não existem. Aliás, por quê a condição no `if` é `!$btn`?

Comment: Não da certo não, Tem hora que ja aparece a mensagem sem ser clicado

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja no primeiro acesso  um warning de `undefined index` é gerado pois o `$_POST` ainda não existe um `isset()/empty()` deve resolver, para mais detalhes veja [Como saber se o form é enviado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89142/91) e [Quando é necessário utilizar o isset?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58355/91)

Answer (score 2):

[**TESTE**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/botao-clicado.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['btn'])){
   echo " O botão foi clicado ";
}else{
   echo "esperando botão ser clicado";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar um meio que se relacione com o POST para verificar se o botão foi clicado, veja o exemplo:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="salario"><br/>
<input type="text" name="bonificacao"><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="validar" value="989">
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Vai" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['validar'])){
$valida = $_POST['validar'];
if($valida == 989){
echo 'Clicado';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta tirar a exclamação da sua condição, você está negando a condição.

Se não der certo tente assim. Coloca o value no `submit`:

```
<form  method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="salario"><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="bonificacao"><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Botão">
</form>
```

Sempre que você submeter ele vai mandar o submit, dai você verifica se está passando o valor:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['btn']) and ($_POST['btn'] <> "")) {
    echo " O botão foi clicado ";
  } else { }
```

Comment: Não deu certo não! assim a mensagem já vem impressa na tela

Comment: Quero mostrar a mensagem somente após o click!!! mais quero fazer isso com PHP

Comment: Cara, os códigos estão no mesmo arquivo?

Comment: Modifiquei o código, dá uma olhada se funciona. Fiz uns testes aqui e funcionou.